# C# Silverlight Programming Technology in general?

Tags: c#, silverlight, blogs

I strive to Keep up but I always feel 3 steps behind.  How do the people here who answer all my stupid questions keep up with everything?

Litterally What websites do you subscribe to?
What Blogs do you read? How often?
How much time in your day do you spend doing it?
What release notes do you care about?
what conferences do you go to

I can't sit idly by any more and expect to keep up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't sit idly by any more and
>   expect to keep up.

Wise words for any profession.

I find it simple to keep up actually.  I read about two books a year on whatever technology interests me, and other than that, as long as I'm actively programming in the technologies I wish to keep up in, I find myself staying up to date, since I'll be searching the web constantly for help and ideas and you just run across the stuff.

Conferences are great when you can get them, but the web is almost as good for keeping up with what goes on at them.  It helps to read the MSDN blogs once in a while if you want to see what Microsoft might currently be up to, but again, you'll run across them if you put any amount of time into programming in .Net.

A lot of my pro-d can be attributed to checking out stackoverflow on a daily basis as well.  Researching interesting questions and reading questions that interest you definitely keeps you sharp.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, i do all the same and I kind of keep up but ill tell you there are a lot of people who know more than me out there..  I kind of like the response of raja below me